# How to manipulate file-paths

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I know this seems like a duplicate, and I am sure it more or less is ... 
However, it really bugs me, and I cannot make anything of the posts before:

I am building a digital edition, utlizing TEI, XML, XSLT, (and probably existDB, maybe I switch to node/javascript).

I built a php-function that should transforme each file in a specified directory to html. (My xsl-file works well)

```
declare function app:XMLtoHTML-forAll ($node as node(), $model as map(*), $query as xs:string?){
    let $ref := xs:string(request:get-parameter("document", ""))
let $xml := doc(concat("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/data/edition/",$ref))
let $xsl := doc("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/resources/xslt/xmlToHtml.xsl")
let $params :=
<parameters>
   {for $p in request:get-parameter-names()
    let $val := request:get-parameter($p,())
    where  not($p = ("document","directory","stylesheet"))
    return
       <param name="{$p}"  value="{$val}"/>
   }
</parameters>

return
    transform:transform($xml, $xsl, $params)
};
```

There is  a list of files in the `apps/BookofOrders/data/edition/` named FolioX.html, where x is the page-number. (I'll probably change names to [FolioNumber].xml, but that's not the issue) 
I am trying to make a text slider (so that when I open the page, a page is presented and further buttons are created, and I can slide to the right and read the rest of the pages).

I have a table of content, that is linked to the transformed files:

```
declare function app:toc($node as node(), $model as map(*)) {
    for $doc in collection("/db/apps/BookOfOrders/data/edition")/tei:TEI
        return
        <li><a href="{concat('http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/BookOfOrders/pages/show.html?document=',functx:substring-after-last(document-uri(root($doc)), '/'))}">{document-uri(root($doc))}</a></li>   
};
```

I guess I am wondering on how to change the link inside to for example Folio29 to Folio30. 
Can I take a part of the provided link and make the destination of a link flexible, similar but not identical to what I did in the toc-function above?

I'd be really happy if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Where is the PHP in this question?

Comment: my bad ... I thought I had a php related problem at first and edited the question, as I resolved the php-"issue" (which was weird punctuation)

Answer (score 0):

Given an expression like `document-uri(root($doc))` (perhaps more simply `util:document-name($doc)`, since you're using eXist) that returns the path to (or filename of) the document ending in "FolioX", you just need to isolate X, then cast it as an integer so you can perform addition/subtraction on the value:

```
document-uri(root($doc)) => substring-after("Folio") => xs:integer()

util:document-name($doc) => substring-after("Folio") => xs:integer()
```

Then add 1, and you've got your next document. Subtract one, and you've got the previous

However, this could lead to broken links: Folio0 or Folio98 (assuming there are only 97). To avoid this, you might want to retrieve determine the complete list of Folios, find the current position, and then never hit 0 or 98:

```
let $this-folio := $doc => util:document-name()
let $collection := $doc => util:collection-name()
let $all-folios := xmldb:get-child-resources($collection)
(: sort the filenames using UCA Numeric collation to ensure Folio2 < Folio10.
 : see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#uca-collations :)
let $sorted-folios := $all-folios => sort("?numeric=yes")
let $this-folio-n := index-of($all-folios, $this-folio)
let $prev-folio := if ($this-folio-n gt 1) then "Folio" || $this-folio-n - 1 else ()
let $next-folio := if ($this-folio-n lt count($all-folios)) then "Folio" || $this-folio-n + 1 else ()
return
    <nav>
         <prev>{$prev-folio}</prev>
         <this>{"Folio" || $this-folio-n}</this>
         <next>{$next-folio}</next>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back, sorry for answering only now ... lots going on at the moment ... 
I get an unexpcted token error on the then in the line before the return (?)

Comment: No worries! Sorry for the error. It's corrected - forgot to close a set of parentheses.

Comment: I tried adding the code, so far without any success, to the app.xql and referred to it on a sample page. However, I get "doc is not set" in this line ```let $this-folio := $doc => util:document-name()``` . Next question would be, how I connect this with my app:XMLtoHTML. So (1) transform xml to html (done that) (2) order files alphabetically (in progress) (3) show all transformed files in alphabetical order (next step)

Comment: Your code referenced a `$doc` parameter, so I used it assuming you would be able to slot the code into the original location. As to your other questions, I’m afraid there isn’t really enough information in your post. Consider posting your app’s code to GitHub and asking for help on the eXist-open mailing list.